Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render. nextjs and shadcn data table
can anyone explain to me or help fix the issue am facing in my code. I am trying to fetch data from my backend in nodejs. and render it in my nextjs frontend app, am getting this errors : "Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render. nextjs and shadcn data table"
here's my components :
"use client"

import React ,{useState, useEffect} from "react"
import {
  ColumnDef,
  ColumnFiltersState,
  SortingState,
  VisibilityState,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getFilteredRowModel,
  getPaginationRowModel,
  getSortedRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table"
import { ArrowUpDown, ChevronDown, MoreHorizontal } from "lucide-react"

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import { Checkbox } from "@/components/ui/checkbox"
import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuCheckboxItem,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuLabel,
  DropdownMenuSeparator,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dropdown-menu"
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input"
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableHeader,
  TableRow,
} from "@/components/ui/table"


import { useQuery } from 'react-query'


// const data: Payment[] = [
//   {
//     id: "m5gr84i9",
//     phone: "316",
//     status: "success",
//     name : "ken99",
//     admin_email: "ken99@yahoo.com",
//     banned : false
//   },
//   {
//     id: "3u1reuv4",
//     phone: "242",
//     status: "success",
//     name : "test",
//     admin_email: "Abe45@gmail.com",
//     banned : false
//   },
//   {
//     id: "derv1ws0",
//     phone: "837",
//     status: "processing",
//     name : "test",
//     admin_email: "Monserrat44@gmail.com",
//     banned : false
//   },
//   {
//     id: "5kma53ae",
//     phone: "874",
//     status: "success",
//     name : "test",
//     admin_email: "Silas22@gmail.com",
//     banned : false
//   },
//   {
//     id: "bhqecj4p",
//     phone: "721",
//     status: "failed",
//     name : "test",
//     admin_email: "carmella@hotmail.com",
//     banned : false
//   },
// ]






// export type Payment = {
//   id: string,
//   name: string,
//   admin_email: string,
//   phone: string,
//   status: string,
//   banned: boolean
// }

export const columns: any = [
  {
    id: "select",
    header: ({ table } : any) => (
      <Checkbox
        checked={
          table.getIsAllPageRowsSelected() ||
          (table.getIsSomePageRowsSelected() && "indeterminate")
        }
        onCheckedChange={(value) => table.toggleAllPageRowsSelected(!!value)}
        aria-label="Select all"
      />
    ),
    cell: ({ row } : any) => (
      <Checkbox
        checked={row.getIsSelected()}
        onCheckedChange={(value) => row.toggleSelected(!!value)}
        aria-label="Select row"
      />
    ),
    enableSorting: false,
    enableHiding: false,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "status",
    header: "Status",
    cell: ({ row } : any) => (
      <div className="capitalize">{row.getValue("status")}</div>
    ),
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "name",
    header: ({ column } : any) => {
      return (
        <Button
          variant="ghost"
          onClick={() => column.toggleSorting(column.getIsSorted() === "asc")}
        >
          Name
          <ArrowUpDown className="ml-2 h-4 w-4" />
        </Button>
      )
    },
    cell: ({ row } : any) => <div className="lowercase">{row.getValue("name")}</div>,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "admin_email",
    header: ({ column } : any) => {
      return (
        <Button
          variant="ghost"
          onClick={() => column.toggleSorting(column.getIsSorted() === "asc")}
        >
          Email
          <ArrowUpDown className="ml-2 h-4 w-4" />
        </Button>
      )
    },
    cell: ({ row } : any) => <div className="lowercase">{row.getValue("admin_email")}</div>,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "phone",
    header: () => <div className="text-right">Phone</div>,
    cell: ({ row } : any) => {
      const phone = parseFloat(row.getValue("phone"))

      return <div className="text-right font-medium">{phone}</div>
    },
  },
  {
    id: "actions",
    enableHiding: false,
    cell: ({ row } : any) => {
      const payment = row.original

      return (
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
            <Button variant="ghost" className="h-8 w-8 p-0">
              <span className="sr-only">Open menu</span>
              <MoreHorizontal className="h-4 w-4" />
            </Button>
          </DropdownMenuTrigger>
          <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
            <DropdownMenuLabel>Actions</DropdownMenuLabel>
            <DropdownMenuItem
              onClick={() => navigator.clipboard.writeText(payment.id)}
            >
              Copy payment ID
            </DropdownMenuItem>
            <DropdownMenuSeparator />
            <DropdownMenuItem>View customer</DropdownMenuItem>
            <DropdownMenuItem>View payment details</DropdownMenuItem>
          </DropdownMenuContent>
        </DropdownMenu>
      )
    },
  },
]

export function SchoolTable() {
  const [sorting, setSorting] = useState<SortingState>([])
  const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = useState<ColumnFiltersState>(
    []
  )
  const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] =
    useState<VisibilityState>({})
  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = useState({})
  const { isLoading, error, data } : any = useQuery('repoData', () =>
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/getSchools?page=1').then(res =>
      res.json()
    )
  )
  
  if (isLoading) return 'Loading...'

  if (error) return 'An error has occurred: ' + error.message

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    state: {
      sorting,
      columnFilters,
      columnVisibility,
      rowSelection,
    },
  })




  return (
   
    <div className="w-full">
      <div className="flex items-center py-4">
        <Input
          placeholder="Filter emails..."
          value={(table.getColumn("email")?.getFilterValue() as string) ?? ""}
          onChange={(event) =>
            table.getColumn("email")?.setFilterValue(event.target.value)
          }
          className="max-w-sm"
        />
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
            <Button variant="outline" className="ml-auto">
              Columns <ChevronDown className="ml-2 h-4 w-4" />
            </Button>
          </DropdownMenuTrigger>
          <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
            {table
              .getAllColumns()
              .filter((column) => column.getCanHide())
              .map((column) => {
                return (
                  <DropdownMenuCheckboxItem
                    key={column.id}
                    className="capitalize"
                    checked={column.getIsVisible()}
                    onCheckedChange={(value) =>
                      column.toggleVisibility(!!value)
                    }
                  >
                    {column.id}
                  </DropdownMenuCheckboxItem>
                )
              })}
          </DropdownMenuContent>
        </DropdownMenu>
      </div>
      <div className="rounded-md border">
        <Table>
          <TableHeader>
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
              <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                  return (
                    <TableHead key={header.id}>
                      {header.isPlaceholder
                        ? null
                        : flexRender(
                            header.column.columnDef.header,
                            header.getContext()
                          )}
                    </TableHead>
                  )
                })}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {table.getRowModel().rows?.length ? (
              table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                <TableRow
                  key={row.id}
                  data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
                >
                  {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                    <TableCell key={cell.id}>
                      {flexRender(
                        cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                        cell.getContext()
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              ))
            ) : (
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell
                  colSpan={columns.length}
                  className="h-24 text-center"
                >
                  No results.
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            )}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-end space-x-2 py-4">
        <div className="flex-1 text-sm text-muted-foreground">
          {table.getFilteredSelectedRowModel().rows.length} of{" "}
          {table.getFilteredRowModel().rows.length} row(s) selected.
        </div>
        <div className="space-x-2">
          <Button
            variant="outline"
            size="sm"
            onClick={() => table.previousPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
          >
            Previous
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="outline"
            size="sm"
            onClick={() => table.nextPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
          >
            Next
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

and this is my backend in nodejs :
exports.getSchools = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const page = req.query.page || 1;
    const limit = req.query.limit || 10;


    const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

 
    const schools = await School.find()
      .skip(skip)
      .limit(limit)
      .select('id logo name admin_email phone plan status banned');


    const totalCount = await School.countDocuments();

    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalCount / limit);

    const pagination = {
      currentPage: page,
      totalPages: totalPages,
      totalCount: totalCount,
    };

    res.status(200).json({ schools, pagination });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error', error: err });
  }
};

the route am fetching data from is http://localhost:5000/api/getSchools?page=1

React relies on the ordering/number of hooks (which for your case are just functions that start with use) in order to properly manage and update state.
Due to this, you have to call all hooks at the top level, before any conditional statements, to prevent unexpected bugs. Reorder your code as the following:
  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    state: {
      sorting,
      columnFilters,
      columnVisibility,
      rowSelection,
    },
  })

  if (isLoading) return 'Loading...'

  if (error) return 'An error has occurred: ' + error.message

